# how to show a textbox if I select a certain option in drop down box in php prep statement?

Tags: javascript, php

We are required to use PHP prepared statement for the Position dropdown, My problem is on how to show/hide a textbox if Physician is selected? For short, if a user selects Physician, the Phycisian's License number textbox will appear

Here's the code

```
<?php
include_once "config.php";

$sql = "SELECT position, posID FROM position order by position";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($position, $pid);            
$stmt->store_result();

echo "<select name='posID' class='form-control'  required>
<option value='' default style='color:gray;'>Position</option>"; 

while ($stmt->fetch()){
echo '<option value="'.$pid.'">'.$position.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="physnum" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Physician's License Number</p></label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
<input name="physnum" class="form-control " id="phys-num" maxlength=5 placeholder="License Number" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
</div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like so far
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you know which one is selected and which one is not?

Comment: use `name='posID[]'` instead.

Comment: @Akshay by posID, I edited my post and include the database

Comment: I'm still not sure. What do you actually want to achieve? Please explain more.

Comment: If a user selects Physician, the Phycisian's License number textbox will appear

Comment: OK, so if he selects Physician, then a textbox named Physician's license number will appear, and if he selects Admin, then a textbox named Admin's license number will appear?

Comment: No need for admin's license number and any, only Physicians License number :D

Comment: Alright, working on a solution here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94531/discussion-between-vista-and-akshay).

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `change` method here.

https://api.jquery.com/change/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <?php
include_once "config.php";

$sql = "SELECT position, posID FROM position order by position";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($position, $pid);            
$stmt->store_result();

echo "<select name='posID' id='posID' class='form-control'  required>
<option value='' default style='color:gray;'>Position</option>"; 

while ($stmt->fetch()){
echo '<option value="'.$pid.'">'.$position.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>

<div id="phys-container">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="physnum" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Physician's License Number</p></label>
<div class="col-xs-7">
<input name="physnum" class="form-control " id="phys-num" maxlength=5 placeholder="License Number" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //on page load, hide the Physician's license number
    $("#phys-container").hide();
})
$("#posID").change(function(e){
    var value = $("#posID").val();
    if(value==4)
    {
        //user's a physician, show the box now
        $("#phys-container").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#phys-container").hide();
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: It's working!, but it is possible, when a user mistakenly selects the Physician, the Physician License number will hide?

Comment: Great Job!! Thank you very much! :D